# golang метод, изменение данных структуры

Tags: golang

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не срабатывает: `mest.st("iii", 33)`

```
import "fmt"

type Mstruct struct {
   name string
   age  int
}

func (m Mstruct) st(a string, b int) {
   m.name = a
   m.age = b
}

func main() {

   mest := Mstruct{"eee", 11}

   fmt.Println(mest)

   mest.st("iii", 33)

   fmt.Println(mest)

}
```

а если изменить на:

```
var mest Mstruct

func (m Mstruct) st(a string, b int) {
  mest.name = a
  mest.age = b
}
```

то отработает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове метода, объект структуры, для которого определен метод, передается в него по значению.
Чтобы изменить объект структуры нужно использовать указатель

```
func (m *Mstruct) st(a string, b int) {
   m.name = a
   m.age = b
}
```

Comment: спасибо. Передаётся по значению, - т.е. работает с копией и указанная команда ```mest.st("iii", 33)``` отрабатывает над этой копией, а ```fmt.Println(mest)``` выводит данные с оригинала. Я правильно понимаю? А как в моём коде можно эту копию *подсмотреть*, чтобы видеть то, что Вы описали.

Comment: Всё верно. Только не понятно что значит подсмотреть?

Comment: После команды ```mest.st("iii", 33)``` , какую команду можно написать, чтобы вывести значение этой копии, над которой изменения произошли, если это возможно конечно.

Comment: похоже так: ```fmt.Println(mest.st("iii", 33))``` , а в фунции ```st``` сделать ```return m```